# Unable to connect to GitHub Apps via SonarQube CE. It keeps returning Unauthorized

Tags: continuous-integration, sonarqube, devops, github-api, github-app

I am working on integrating SonarQube within my Organizations' CI pipeline, and getting last this huddle is the last step to doing that. I need help with the problem below:

I am trying to connect my SonarQube Community Edition deployment to GitHub, and I did set up a GitHub app, and used the credentials to set up a GitHub Project on SonarQube. However, whenever I try to initiate the project, I keep getting returned unauthorized: 'You're not authorized to access this page. Please contact the administrator.'. This is at the URL: https:///sessions/unauthorized.

I get this in the logs:

`WARN  web[AYNny08VYY7aX7LCAAXh][o.s.s.a.AuthenticationError] No provider key found in URI`